# How to add ActivityIndicator to shell flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms.shell

I added a logout button to the `FlyoutFooter` of the shell. After clicking it, it takes a certain waiting time to connect to the server, so I need to add an `ActivityIndicator` in the flyout.

```
  <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <Grid>
            <Button Text="Logout"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

How can I add it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FlyoutContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#replace-flyout-content) property:

```
   <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <Grid>
            <Button Text="Logout"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

```
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.Children.Add(new ActivityIndicator()
            {
                IsRunning = true,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            });

            Current.FlyoutContent = grid;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            FlyoutContent = null;
        }
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Although the method is a little different, I solved the problem according to your ideas.
I am not very familiar with Strack Overflow, I accidentally edited your answer, please forgive me

Comment: No issue at all never mind :)