# ActivityIndicator with Shell top navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have a shell navigation with some ShellContent, and the employees menu took much time to load data. I have searched to add ActivityIndicator, but I have no idea how to implement.

```
<Shell ..>
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>

                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Color="Black" />

    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

<ShellContent x:Name="home"
Route="main"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Dashboard}" />
</Shell>
<ShellContent x:Name="listEmp"
Route="Employees"
IsVisible="{Binding IsEmployees}"
ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate home:Employees}" />
</Shell>
```

There is a solution, instead of ContentTemplate we change MenuItem:

```
 <MenuItem Command="{Binding LoadEmployeesCmd}" />
```

and in ViewModel :

```
        public ICommand LoadEmployeesCmd=> new Command(() => LoadEmployees());

        private async void LoadEmployees()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Views.Employees), typeof(Views.Employees));

          await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Employees");

            IsBusy = false;
            Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;

        }
```

I am looking if there is solution without changing ShellContent to MenuItem, because in MenuItem there is no IsVisible...

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66028834/199364) might give you an idea. I'm not sure how to adapt what they did, but it might get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the IsBusy property with AppShell's IsBusy and change AppShell's is Busy in load method like:
**AppShell.xmal.cs:**

```
    public AppShell(){
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    BindingContext=this;}
```

**viewmodel:**

```
  private async void LoadEmployees()
    {
    AppShell.Current.IsBusy=true;//change the property

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(Views.Employees), typeof(Views.Employees));

      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Employees");

        AppShell.Current.IsBusy=false;
        Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;

    }
```